# Можно ли создать массив со словам с неизвестными окончаниями?

Tags: php, массивы

Можно ли в PHP создать массив со словами с неизвестными окончаниями? Допустим при сравнении массивов(array_intersect) принимался ответ Москва, Москве, Москвой. Просто предусмотреть все варианты невозможно+ это займёт очень много места.

Comment: а задача какая? как сами решали её?

Comment: с `preg_match` это можно... Но и проще можно - уточните задачу

Comment: @DNS, я получаю предложение, все слова этого предложения помещаю в массив. Дальше мне нужно понимать смысл предложения, чтобы выполнять в зависимости от этого действия. Но у слов могут быть разные окончания и тогда определения задачи затрудняется, а написание массива всех возможных ответов займет очень много времени, места и будет тормозить всю систему в целом при проверке. Preg_match не очень подходит, надо получать значение каждого слова в предложении, слишком много таких функций надо написать.

Comment: @Naumov, нахождение слова в массиве вне зависимости от окончания. Сейчас решается употреблением общих конструкций и большой базой слов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Библиотека Phpmorphy должна подойти для решения этой задачи. С её помощью можно получить нормальную форму слова. Только для его работы необходимо дополнительно скачать специальные словари.

Вот пример работы:

```
var_dump($morphy->lemmatize('КОЛБАСЫ')); // array('КОЛБАСА')
var_dump($morphy->lemmatize('ТЕСТ')); // array('ТЕСТ', 'ТЕСТО')
```

Получается, можно брать полученное предложение, разбивать его на слова, и каждое слово прогонять через phpmorphy, чтобы получить базовую форму слова. Следовательно, не нужно будет прописывать все возможные варианты слов со всеми окончаниями, спряжениями. Достаточно только найти базовую форму слова.

http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/

[Мануал](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/manual)

Comment: Списки словоформ можно взять из словарей открытого корпуса русского языка (http://opencorpora.org/)

Comment: К библиотеке надо относиться внимательно, работает не в 100% случаев, словари регулярно надо править самостоятельно, либо искать хорошо проработанные кем-то

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал примерно так

```
$tpl = "пап";
$arr = array("мама","папа","папе");
foreach($arr as $wrd)
    if(strpos($wrd,$tpl)===0)
        echo "пройдено по шаблону:",$wrd,"<br>";
    else
        echo "HE пройдено по шаблону:",$wrd,"<br>";
```

> HE пройдено по шаблону:мама
>
> пройдено по шаблону:папа
>
> пройдено по шаблону:папе

Но в данном коде по шаблону пройдут слова типа паперть, папуас и т.п. Надо хорошо подумать над выделением шаблона